# Can someone please tell me if this is the right sql query i am using?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am trying to find the number of orders from a transaction table. Here's the query that i have used:

```
   select t.productid,
   EXTRACT(week from t.dt)as Week_,
   count (t.productid) as Orders
   FROM (SELECT distinct productid, dt from Transaction  WHERE client='abc') as t 
   GROUP BY t.productid, Week_
   ORDER BY Week_ asc;
```

I am trying to find the unique orders for each productid grouped by week. Is this the correct approach ? I would really appreciate some insights and opinions. If I use this query instead it just gives orders as 1 for each productid :

```
select t.productid,EXTRACT(week from t.dt) as WEEK, count(distinct t.productid) as  Orders  from 
Transaction t
where t.client ='abc'
GROUP BY WEEK, t.productid
ORDER BY WEEK asc;
```

which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your approach is not strictly correct.  A client could order the same product twice in a week, in two different orders.  Presumably there is an `orderid` of some sort in the transaction table.  If so, you can do:

```
   SELECT t.productid, EXTRACT(week from t.dt)as Week_, count(distinct orderid) as orders
   FROM Transaction
   WHERE client ='abc'
   GROUP BY t.productid, Week_
   ORDER BY Week_ asc;
```

If you want the number of clients, you would do:

```
   SELECT t.productid, EXTRACT(week from t.dt)as Week_, count(distinct client) as clients
   FROM Transaction
   GROUP BY t.productid, Week_
   ORDER BY Week_ asc;
```